# Show text depending of property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to show the text online or offline, depending on the value of a property. So if the property camera.key is null there the text offline has to be shown. Otherwise, the text online has to be shown.

So I have this template:

```
<h3>Camera sensoren</h3>
<table>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last update</th>
    <th>Status sensor</th>
    <tr *ngFor="let camera of sensorStatusCollection.cameraSensors">
    <td>{{ camera.key }}</td>
    <td>{{ camera.latestTimestamp }}</td>
    <td *ngIf ="camera.key === null ? online : offline "></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But what I have to declare in the typescript part?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just modify your code, put it in `td` body

```html
<td>{{camera.key === null ? "online" : "offline" }}</td>
```

for better understanding to `*ngIF` if you want to use it, it an angular structural directive here you can find more about it, what is it and how to use it [NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf), here is an example for you:

```html
<td *ngIf ="camera.key === null">online</td>
<td *ngIf ="camera.key !== null">offline</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it works. And of course, if it is null === offline. so the other way around. But that are the details